# Is there an option to generate test methods from the source PHP class using my template (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, testing, phpstorm

Firstly I want to ask You if it is possible to automatically generate test template methods in test class from selected source class in PhpStorm?

For example:

I want to generate test for that class:

```
class ReportMyOrdersController extends InitializationController
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->doSomethingImportant();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $options = [
            'option1' => 'surrender',
            'option2' => 'fight'
        ];

        return placeOrder('option' . rand(1, 2));
    }

    public function search()
    {
        return searchEverywereRightNow('answer');
    }

    public function doSomethingImportant()
    {
        return 'somethingImportant';
    }

}
```

Which should looks like that:

```
class ReportMyConversationTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function shouldInit()
    {
       //given

       //when

       //then
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function shouldIndex()
    {
       //given

       //when

       //then
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function shouldSearch()
    {
       //given

       //when

       //then
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function shouldDoSomethingImportant()
    {
       //given

       //when

       //then
    }
}
```

Is it possible ? I am programming using Test Driven Development method and that would make my test-making a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not implemented yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16258